# Organizing text blocks as rows in R

Tags: r, text-mining, text-manipulation

I have a text file containing details of about 1000 articles, each containing the same items (PMC, PMID..... AID, SO). I need to have every article details as a single row such that the item names are read as column names, and the respective content as row values:

```
PMC              PMID        ........      SO

PMC8882595       35237547    ........      Front ....69001
PMC8967719       35296856    ........      Child Yo... 040
```

The author names and affiliations columns (FAU, AU, AD) in between are repeated, and I just need to extract the country name from that content, if possible. Or just merge them otherwise.

I am really sorry about the poor phrasing of the question. Here is a glimpse of first two articles to describe it better.

```
PMC - PMC8882595
PMID- 35237547
IS  - 2296-2565 (Electronic)
VI  - 10
DP  - 2022
TI  - Poverty Vulnerability and Health Risk Action Path of Families of Rural Elderly
      With Chronic Diseases: Empirical Analysis of 1,852 Families in Central and
      Western China.
LID - 776901
AB  - Health poverty has become the most important cause of poverty and return to
      poverty. Understanding the health risk factors and action paths of poverty in
      families of rural elderly with chronic diseases is important to alleviate return 
      to poverty because of illness. This study selected families with at least one
      elderly member (over 60 years old) with chronic diseases (sample size was 1,852
      people and localities, the causes of poverty and returning to poverty, and the
      types of poverty vulnerabilities. The use efficiency of medical insurance should 
      be further improved, and the responsibility of medical insurance targeted poverty
      alleviation must be clarified.
FAU - Ma, Ying
AU  - Ma Y
AD  - Department of Health Management, School of Medicine and Health Management, Tongji
      Medical College, Huazhong University of Science and Technology, Wuhan, China
FAU - Xiang, Qin
AU  - Xiang Q
AD  - Department of Health Management, School of Medicine and Health Management, Tongji
      Medical College, Huazhong University of Science and Technology, Wuhan, China
FAU - Yan, Chaoyang
AU  - Yan C
AD  - Department of Health Management, School of Medicine and Health Management, Tongji
      Medical College, Huazhong University of Science and Technology, Wuhan, China
FAU - Liao, Hui
AU  - Liao H
AD  - Department of Health Management, School of Medicine and Health Management, Tongji
      Medical College, Huazhong University of Science and Technology, Wuhan, China
FAU - Wang, Jing
AU  - Wang J
AD  - Department of Health Management, School of Medicine and Health Management, Tongji
      Medical College, Huazhong University of Science and Technology, Wuhan, China
LA  - eng
PT  - Journal Article
DEP - 20220214
PHST- 2021/09/14 [received]
PHST- 2022/01/20 [accepted]
TA  - Front Public Health
JT  - Frontiers in Public Health
AID - 10.3389/fpubh.2022.776901 [doi]
SO  - Front Public Health. 2022 Feb 14;10:. doi:10.3389/fpubh.2022.776901.


    
    
PMC - PMC6107082
PMID- 30147212
IS  - 0190-7409 (Print)
VI  - 79
DP  - 2017 Aug
TI  - Family poverty and neighborhood poverty: Links with children’s school readiness
      before and after the Great Recession.
PG  - 368-84
AB  - This paper examines how neighborhood and family poverty predict children’s
      academic skills and classroom behavior at school entry, and whether associations 
      additional support.
FAU - Wolf, Sharon
AU  - Wolf S
AD  - Graduate School of Education, University of Pennsylvania, 3700 Walnut Street,
      Room 340, Philadelphia, PA 19104, United States
FAU - Magnuson, Katherine A.
AU  - Magnuson KA
AD  - Institute for Research on Poverty, University of Wisconsin – Madison, 1180
      Observatory Drive, Madison, WI 53706, United States
FAU - Kimbro, Rachel T.
AU  - Kimbro RT
AD  - Rice University, 6100 Main St., MS-28, Houston, TX 77005, United States
LA  - eng
PT  - Journal Article
DEP - 20170623
TA  - Child Youth Serv Rev
JT  - Children and youth services review
AID - 10.1016/j.childyouth.2017.06.040 [doi]
MID - NIHMS984695
SO  - Child Youth Serv Rev. 2017 Aug;79:368-84. Epub 2017 Jun 23
      doi:10.1016/j.childyouth.2017.06.040.
```

Comment: Is the `glimpse` in a txt file?

Comment: Your data is not well structured for easy expansion. For instance, you have two `PHST` but 3+ each of `FAU`, `AU`, and `AD`. If you have not thought about it yet, then you need to think about how to aggregate your different `PHST` values, and if you just want a collapsed string of countries (from the fau/au/ad fields). The general rule of recycling (to be safe) is "1 or the same length", which is not true here, so you _must_ aggregate everything (that has more than 1). I suggest you provide *complete* expected output (not just a semblance) based on this input.

Comment: Thank you for the nice explanation. Making a complete example output was a little difficult as the content is too large for some columns, such as the titles and abstract. The expected df is relaxable, and the problematic columns can be removed/merged.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an admittedly brute-force start for you.

Up front, though, you will need to put some thought onto how you want to aggregate your fields. In general, all of the fields (e.g., `"PMC"`, `"PHST"`, `"FAU"`) must recycling safely, with a length of exactly 1 or the same non-1 length from each group. In this data, in the first batch of data, you have `PHST` with length 2 and `FAU` with length 5. I know this is known based on the variable data, and that's fine, but that means you need to come up with a clean way to aggregate them. Some options might include list-columns or text-reduction using tokenization, pattern-matching, or whatever. You said you want to extract just the country from the multiple `AU` fields, that's fine, but ... that's not always easy given the free-text flow of those fields.

I'm addressing everything except how to find country names and reduce those fields. I strongly encourage looking into list-columns (as opposed to my naive string-concatenation) and some other functions to do the aggregation. (Perhaps another question?)

For now, my naive aggregator:

```r
agg_fun <- function(x, fld) {
  # do something different based on fld[1] such as extract a country
  paste(x, collapse = " ")
}
```

First, to read in that data, I'll use some bespoke code to turn it into a frame with which we can work a little more easily:

```r
txt <- readLines("~/StackOverflow/12121693/72706285.txt")
tmp1 <- tmp2 <- character(0)
leadsp <- grepl("^\\s", txt)
tmp1[!leadsp] <- sub("^(\\S+)\\s*-.*", "\\1", txt[!leadsp])
tmp2[!leadsp] <- sub("^\\S+\\s*-\\s*(.*)", "\\1", txt[!leadsp])
tmp2[leadsp] <- sub("^ *", "", txt[leadsp])

tmpdat <- tibble(field = tmp1, value = tmp2)
tmpdat
# # A tibble: 82 x 2
#    field value                                                                         
#    <chr> <chr>                                                                         
#  1 PMC   PMC8882595                                                                    
#  2 PMID  35237547                                                                      
#  3 IS    2296-2565 (Electronic)                                                        
#  4 VI    10                                                                            
#  5 DP    2022                                                                          
#  6 TI    Poverty Vulnerability and Health Risk Action Path of Families of Rural Elderly
#  7 NA    With Chronic Diseases: Empirical Analysis of 1,852 Families in Central and    
#  8 NA    Western China.                                                                
#  9 LID   776901                                                                        
# 10 AB    Health poverty has become the most important cause of poverty and return to   
# # ... with 72 more rows
```

With that, here's a dplyr/tidyr flow using that data:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr) # pivot_wider
tibble(field = tmp1, value = tmp2) %>%
  filter(nzchar(trimws(field)) | nzchar(trimws(value))) %>%
  group_by(grp = cumsum(!is.na(field))) %>%
  summarize(field = field[1], value = paste(value, collapse = " ")) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  group_by(grp = cumsum(field == "PMC"), field) %>%
  summarize(value = agg_fun(value, field[1])) %>%
  pivot_wider(grp, names_from = "field", values_from = "value") %>%
  ungroup()
# # A tibble: 2 x 22
#     grp AB                                      AD                                      AID        AU        DEP    DP     FAU          IS       JT        LA    LID    PHST      PMC   PMID  PT     SO                TA     TI                         VI    MID   PG   
#   <int> <chr>                                   <chr>                                   <chr>      <chr>     <chr>  <chr>  <chr>        <chr>    <chr>     <chr> <chr>  <chr>     <chr> <chr> <chr>  <chr>             <chr>  <chr>                      <chr> <chr> <chr>
# 1     1 Health poverty has become the most imp~ Department of Health Management, Schoo~ 10.3389/f~ Ma Y Xia~ 20220~ 2022   Ma, Ying Xi~ 2296-25~ Frontier~ eng   776901 2021/09/~ PMC8~ 3523~ Journ~ "Front Public He~ Front~ Poverty Vulnerability and~ 10    NA    NA   
# 2     2 This paper examines how neighborhood a~ Graduate School of Education, Universi~ 10.1016/j~ Wolf S M~ 20170~ 2017 ~ Wolf, Sharo~ 0190-74~ Children~ eng   NA     NA        PMC6~ 3014~ Journ~ "Child Youth Ser~ Child~ Family poverty and neighb~ 79    NIHM~ 368-~
```

You can likely now discard `grp` (it was artifical), and if you look deeper into many of these strings, you'll realize some of them are quite long.

Comment: That's a great help! Enough to get started. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

in Base R you could do:

```
df <- read.dcf(textConnection(sub(" *- *",':',readLines('my_file.txt'))),all=T)

        PMC     PMID                     IS VI       DP ....
1 PMC8882595 35237547 2296-2565 (Electronic) 10     2022 ....
2 PMC6107082 30147212      0190-7409 (Print) 79 2017 Aug ....
```

Note that the duplicated values are put in a list. eg:

```
df$FAU
[[1]]
[1] "Ma, Ying"      "Xiang, Qin"    "Yan, Chaoyang" "Liao, Hui"     "Wang, Jing"   

[[2]]
[1] "Wolf, Sharon"           "Magnuson, Katherine A." "Kimbro, Rachel T."
```

Which indicates the values from the first document and the values from the second document

Comment: Thank you for the code. It ddoes not seem to work for the data though. I keep getting the following error:  Invalid DCF format. Regular lines must have a tag. Offending lines start with:...

Comment: @Nile does your text file look exactly as provided in the example above?

Comment: Yes, the names of the items are the same for each article. Maybe the issue here is that for some articles there are too many authors (FAU).

Comment: @Nile too many has no problem for the `read.dcf` I used exactly that. seems your lines start with no tags. ie you need to trim the whitespace. Try the code as it is, only change the part with `readLines('myfile.txt')` to `trimws(readLines('myfile.txt'))`

Comment: Thank you for the new code. It seems like the data is a bit messy to apply this code. Now there is a new error: 'Line starting 'Western China. ...' is malformed!' Do you have any idea what might be causing this? I have checked the file and didn't find any line that starts with the said words.

Comment: @Nile first does any of the codes I provided work on your example data(Not the main data, but the data you provided here)?

Comment: try this also(On your example data) `read.dcf(textConnection(sub(" *(\\w+) *- *",'\\1:',readLines('my_file.txt'))),all=TRUE)`

Comment: Thank you so much for your responses! I tried the first code successfully with a small number of papers, but not for the entire text, unfortunately. The very last code ran without for five different datasets I tried, and it extracts the target columns correctly but also pulls some text words to columns with empty rows e.g. which, accurate, covid, jump. So I have to clean them manually to be able to apply rbind.

Comment: @Nile you need to anchor your pattern ie `^ *\\(w+) *- *` and maintain `\\1:` as the replacement